# Truncating a number using string find method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's a piece of code

```
numstring = str(15.555555) 
num = float(numstring[:numstring.find('.')+4])
```

I know the above code stores 15.555 in num. What does the '+4' specify in the above code?

Comment: It finds the index of the '.' char and then takes the following 3 characters as decimal points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
numstring.find('.')
```

gives the index of the first occurrency of `'.'`. In your case it's the only occurrency.

Let's call it:

```
index = numstring.find('.')
```

Then, you are slicing `numstring` from its beginning (index 0) to `index+4`.

This means you are taking the substring that goes from the beginning to 4 chars after the `'.'` including the point itself, meaning 3 decimals after the point.

So:

```
"12.34567"
```

becomes:

```
"12.345"
```

Comment: And "0.0004" becomes "0.0".

Comment: Nope, it becomes "0.000"

Comment: Well, I meant after the `float(...)`.

Comment: If you are under the impression that 0.000 is the correct result, try "0.00004".

Answer (score 0):

while good answers are given, they are all using a conversion to and from strings. This is how you do it with the `math` module, which does not require strings:

```
import math

number = 15.55555555
decimal_precision = 3
f = 10**decimal_precision
result = math.floor(number*f)/f
print(result)

# one liner 
# result = math.floor(number*1000)/1000
```

output:

```
15.555
```